# Django does not safe the values of the BooleanFields

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have the following form with few boolean fields:

```py
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    guardianSource = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'id':'guardianSource'}),required=False)
    bbcSource = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    independentSource = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    categoryCoronaVirus = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    categoryPolitics = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    categorySport = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    #Telling the registration form what kind of data we are going to be modelling/ what the form needs to look like
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ("username", "password1", "password2", "guardianSource", "bbcSource", "independentSource", "categoryCoronaVirus", "categoryPolitics", "categorySport")
```

The register template looks as following:

```html
<form class="form-signin" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>



  <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required autofocus>

  <label for="inputPassword1" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password1" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

  <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password2" id="inputPassword2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <br>
  <div  class="form-control">
    <p><b>Please choose news sources!</b></p>

    <label for="guardianSource" >The Guardian</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="guardianSource">
    <br>
    <label for="bbcSource" >BBC News</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="bbcSource">
    <br>
    <label for="independentSource" >The Independent</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="independentSource">
   </div>
   <br>
   <div  class="form-control">
    <p><b>Please choose news category!</b></p>

    <label for="categoryCoronaVirus" >Corona Virus</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="categoryCoronaVirus">
    <br>
    <label for="categoryPolitics" >Politics</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="categoryPolitics">
    <br>
    <label for="categorySport" >Sport</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="categorySport">
   </div>

    {% for field in registration_form %}
        <p>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p class="alert alert-danger card-header text-center flashit"> {{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if registration_form.non_field_errors %}
        <div style="color:red;">
                <p>{{registration_form.non_field_errors}}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
  <h6 class="text-muted">
     NOTE: You <b>MUST</b> select at least 1 choice for each!!!
  </h6>
    <div  id="error_message"> </div>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="valthisform()">Register</button>

</form>
```

There is a JavaScript function that checks if at least 1 checkbox for category and 1 for source is selected before submitting the form:

```
function valthisform(){

                var guardianSource = document.getElementById("guardianSource").checked;
                var bbcSource = document.getElementById("bbcSource").checked;
                var independentSource = document.getElementById("independentSource").checked;
                var checkedSource = false;

                var categoryCoronaVirus = document.getElementById("categoryCoronaVirus").checked;
                var categoryPolitics = document.getElementById("categoryPolitics").checked;
                var categorySport = document.getElementById("categorySport").checked;
                var checkedCategory = false;



                if(guardianSource ===true || bbcSource===true || independentSource===true){
                    checkedSource = true;
                }
                if(categoryCoronaVirus===true || categoryPolitics===true || categorySport===true){
                    checkedCategory = true;
                }

                if(checkedSource ===false && checkedCategory===false){
                    document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger card-header text-center flashit"><strong>Warning!</strong> No source and category selected!</div>';
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else if(checkedSource ===false ){
                    document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger card-header text-center flashit"><strong>Warning!</strong> No source selected!</div>';
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else if(checkedCategory===false){
                    document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger card-header text-center flashit"><strong>Warning!</strong> No  category selected!</div>';
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

        }
```

The problem is: when I don't check any checkbox when registering the JavaScript function works as it is supposed to - it prevents saving the data into the database and prints whatever it supposed to. After printing the warning message, I check few boxes and submit the form. Form submits and redirects to home page, however, once I look into the database the checked boolean values are not saved - they are all False. 
My django view for register is:

```py
def registration(request):
    context = {}

    if request.user.is_authenticated: # If user is logged in, redirect to home screen, they cannot register again!
        return redirect('home')
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else: # GET request
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

EDIT: 
I finally found the bug after going through the commits on git and comparing files to earliest commits.
Basically the code from the register template:

```py
<label for="guardianSource" >The Guardian</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="guardianSource">
    <br>
    <label for="bbcSource" >BBC News</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="bbcSource">
    <br>
    <label for="independentSource" >The Independent</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="independentSource">
   </div>
   <br>
   <div  class="form-control">
    <p><b>Please choose news category!</b></p>

    <label for="categoryCoronaVirus" >Corona Virus</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="categoryCoronaVirus">
    <br>
    <label for="categoryPolitics" >Politics</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="categoryPolitics">
    <br>
    <label for="categorySport" >Sport</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="categorySport">
   </div>
```

I have renamed for some reason the name attribute of each checkbox. 
After changing the values to:

```py
<label for="guardianSource" >The Guardian</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guardianSource" id="guardianSource">
    <br>
    <label for="bbcSource" >BBC News</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bbcSource" id="bbcSource">
    <br>
    <label for="independentSource" >The Independent</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="independentSource" id="independentSource">
   </div>
   <br>
   <div  class="form-control">
    <p><b>Please choose news category!</b></p>

    <label for="categoryCoronaVirus" >Corona Virus</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categoryCoronaVirus" id="categoryCoronaVirus">
    <br>
    <label for="categoryPolitics" >Politics</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categoryPolitics" id="categoryPolitics">
    <br>
    <label for="categorySport" >Sport</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categorySport" id="categorySport">
   </div>
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to repeat some of the model fields in your form again. That's not necessary and might cause this error. If you use the following in models.py and forms.py, then calling the save() method should save all fields in your database.

models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    guardianSource = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    bbcSource = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    independentSource = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    categoryCoronaVirus = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    categoryPolitics = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    categorySport = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ("username", "password1", "password2", "guardianSource", "bbcSource", "independentSource", "categoryCoronaVirus", "categoryPolitics", "categorySport")
        widget = {'guardianSource': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'id':'guardianSource'})}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I also tried to not "activating" the JavaScript function by ticking all the check boxes on register, but it is still not saving the values in the database.
Users have like a Settings account page  that is using almost the same code as the registration template and it works, it saves the values.